# autotools: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: cross-compiling, autotools, osdev

I am building an x86_64-elf kernel on OS X. My build system is autotools. I successfully compiled gcc to cross-compile for x86_64-elf on OS X. When I run the configure script generated from autotools I have an issue:

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

So I look at config.log and see:

```
cannot find crt0.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This makes perfect sense. The cross-compiler won't generate an executable because there is no associated runtime. But I don't need or want my compiler to generate an executable, I'm going to link it appropriately for my bootloader. How do I tell autotools to not check this?

Comment: Can't you just set the `CC` variable in your `configure.ac` script? It might not work however, as other tests may create executable files that the script tries to run.

Comment: I set the CC variable when I run configure, its really bad form to set it in configure.ac. Regardless, that doesn't answer the question of how I get it to stop checking if the compiler can create executables.

Comment: Tell configure that you are cross-compiling. Use `./configure --host=x86_64-unknown-linux`. If the build type is different from the host type, certain tests may be skipped.

Comment: I am doing that, --host=x86_64-elf, it still fails.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you are specifying the following gcc flags when you run the configure script (add them to the CFLAGS environment variable):

```
-nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -ffreestanding
```

If you don't know how to append these to the end of CFLAGS, try something like:

```
export CFLAGS=$CFLAGS -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -ffreestanding
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DARWIN_VERSION_FULL=darwin`uname -r`
./configure --build=x86_64-apple-${DARWIN_VERSION_FULL} --host=x86_64-unknown-linux
```

Now `configure` should be in cross compiling mode, and stop running that test.

Comment: Does not change anything. For what its worth, I'm not building for x86_64-unknown-linux, I build for x86_64-elf.

Comment: Are you setting up the environment variables   (e.g. CC, LD, etc.) to point to the cross compiler?